# Magento 1.9.2.1 related product not adding correctly

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9

I am building a Magento theme and am having trouble customising the way the related products work.

By default as some of you will be aware the related products system works with checkboxes. You simply tick related items and click the main "add to cart" button to add all the products at once.

I am wanting to add an "add to cart" button and quantity input for **individual related items**, so I can add them individually to the cart without adding the main product.

I added the following code from the link below to the template/catalog/product/list/related.phtml.

http://sarathlal.com/add-to-cart-button-in-related-products-on-product-detail-page-magento/

This adds the "add to cart" button and quantity input perfectly but when the "add to cart" button is clicked on **first** related product in the list the **main product** on the page is added instead of the related item. When I click the **second, third, fourth etc** in the list it weirdly adds the correct related item.

I have re-indexed everything and flushed all caches.

Can anybody advise? I would really appreciate it.

[Screenshot to help with my description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e70zQ.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anybody reading this thread is having similar issues I have solved the problem. The issue was within the catalog/product/view.phtml file. I was rendering the related.phtml file within the products view.phtml **form** HTML tags. I rendered the related.phtml block outside the form and all is working.

The answer submitted by Shakir Khan will allow a "add to cart" button for the related item. if you are like me and want the quantity as well use the below code, and place it withing the loop in your related.phtml.

```
<form action="<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_item) ?>" method="post" id="product_addtocart_form_<?php echo $_item->getId()?>"<?php if($_item->getOptions()): ?> enctype="multipart/form-data"<?php endif; ?>>
       <?php if(!$_item->isGrouped()): ?>
                <input type="text" name="qty" id="qty" maxlength="12" value="<?php echo ($this->getMinimalQty($_item)?$this->getMinimalQty($_item):1) ?>" />
                <label for="qty"><?php echo $this->__('Qty') ?>:</label>
       <?php endif; ?>
       <button type="button" onclick="this.form.submit(this)"><span><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?></span></span></span></button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

app/design/frontend/default/your theme/template/catalog/product/list/related.phtml

add below line of code in related .phtml page:-

```
<form action="<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_item); ?>" method="post" ?>"<?php if($_item->getOptions()): ?> enctype="multipart/form-data"<?php endif; ?>>
<button type="button" onclick="this.form.submit()"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?></span></span></button>
</form>
```

in view.phtml there a script which add only one product to cart because of from id

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
        var productAddToCartForm = new VarienForm('product_addtocart_form');
```

I have removed id "product_addtocart_form" check now

Comment: try my code or try this example because add to cart button in view.phtml work differently. check this link for add to cart in view.phtml     http://bsscommerce.com/blog/magento-change-the-form-of-displaying-related-products/

Comment: Added your form code in directly and still same issues I am afraid.

Comment: what error did you see now check console and make developer mode true

Comment: Debug is on and I have three errors when viewing the product view.phtml. all with this "unreachable code after return statement" the files the error occurs in are product.js, configurable.js and calendar.js

Comment: can you post your view.phtml

Comment: I have fixed the issue! thanks ever so much for your help and time Shakir, look at my answer above if you are interested in what I did.